# Looking at Membership class with reflector

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I was just going through user registration process in asp.net (System.Web.Security.Membership class) with reflector and spotted that some code was commented out

```
public static bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{ 
    return Provider.ValidateUser(username, password);
    /* 
    if (retVal) { 
        PerfCounters.IncrementCounter(AppPerfCounter.MEMBER_SUCCESS);
        WebBaseEvent.RaiseSystemEvent(null, WebEventCodes.AuditMembershipAuthenticationSuccess, username); 
    }
    else {
        PerfCounters.IncrementCounter(AppPerfCounter.MEMBER_FAIL);
        WebBaseEvent.RaiseSystemEvent(null, WebEventCodes.AuditMembershipAuthenticationFailure, username); 
    }

    return retVal; 
    */
}
```

Now I'm puzzled with two things. 
    1. Does MS lives such legacy code commented out "for later" 
    2. How can Reflector read comments in code. After all comments shouldn't be compiled into DLL, aren't they?

Comment: This looks like a fluke of some kind, because comments indeed do not get compiled into the bytecode. Maybe it's some kind of construct that can't quite be expressed in C#, or reflector is just failing?

Comment: I have no idea. But maybe someone could try it with their copy of Reflector and .Net 4.0?